# Some URLs don't give the page not found error but error 404

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, hyperlinks

I've noticed that in SO sites some URLs don't give the standard error "Page not Found" with the waffles but a 404 error.

For example these URLs:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/

are giving the standard error page, but if I add another slash (**the 32nd**), the Web Server gives another page, in some way "out of control":

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/

I don't know if it's so important to notice but I wanted to try, because I work as programmer and sometimes customers request that any wrong URL of the same kind should give the same error page.

Note: I've tried with google.com and the result is worse even with just /a/a, so maybe the problem is not so important. :)

Comment: For the firth time I laugh about an error summary.

Comment: :) Believe it or not but more than once they asked me to make these checks on some websites.

Comment: Meh, who is doing this? And if they are, do we care?

Comment: Well, they want centralize the error controls, log everything inside the website environment, check unusual requests... things like that.

Comment: I've posted it just as a curiosity, maybe it could be a hint for some user, who knows.

Comment: Maybe because 31 is the most you can store in 5 bits?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/aa/ produces the same buggy result - this is clearly purely a result of the number of path components, not its length.